# cassandra ordering or sorting

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nosql

Need to fetch latest result in a table without mentioning partion key . For example need latest tweets .Problems facing as follows,

```
    create table test2.threads(
    thread text ,
    created_date timestamp,
    forum_name text,
    subject text,
    posted_by text,
    last_reply_timestamp timestamp,
     PRIMARY KEY (thread,last_reply_timestamp)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (last_reply_timestamp DESC);
```

Only if i know the partion key , I can retrive data .

```
select * from test2.threads where thread='one' order by last_reply_timestamp DESC;
```

How can i get latest threads sort by desc without mentioning where condition?

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is not suited for that purpose. The partitions are not ordered. You'd have to loop over the partition keys, fetch a few and then see which ones are the most recent at the application level.